# Edited posts after 2,000 reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, editing

Search yielding no results for this. I noticed that, after I reached 2k reputation, my edits did not add 2 to my reputation. Is there any reason for this? Frankly, I don't see why the +2 reputation (which could be taken as a token of appreciation for caring to edit posts) should not apply after someone is a bit experienced. Of course, I know there are badges for a certain number of edited posts, but some people here care about reputation a lot. It's not that I'll stop editing posts after this. I'll edit every post which I feel needs to be edited. But I just don't see the need to remove the +2 token.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now that you've reached 2000 reputation, your edits are no longer reviewed by others - you submit your edits and they go through immediately. Lots of people would game the system if there were an action that always brings reputation points and is not checked by reviewers.

[See this thread on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169889/161783) for a similar response.

[See this thread on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/161783) for the official explanation of the suggested edits feature.